# Get closest index of value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, closest

I try to get closest index of value in array. Index must be closest **to up value** and does not depend on the order - asc or desc

I'm currently using function which return closest index to up but array must be asc (desc missing).

```js
function closestIndex(value, arr, from, to) {
  from = (typeof from !== 'undefined') ? from : 0;
  to = (typeof to !== 'undefined') ? to : arr.length;
  
  if (from >= to) {
    return to - 1;
  }
  
  var mid = Math.floor((from + to) / 2);
  if (arr[mid] > value) {
    return closestIndex(value, arr, from, mid);
  }
  
  return closestIndex(value, arr, mid + 1, to);
}

var arr = [10, 15, 20, 50, 100];
console.log(closestIndex(8, arr)); //index: -1
console.log(closestIndex(10, arr)); //index: 0
console.log(closestIndex(14, arr)); //index: 0
console.log(closestIndex(1000, arr)); //index: 4
```

I should receive these values:

```
//var arr = [100,50,20,15,10]; //same, just reversed values
//val: 8 = idx: 4
//val: 10 = idx: 4
//val: 14 = idx: 3
//val: 1000 = idx: -1
```

Comment: Why is `5` a result when there is no element at index `5` in the array?

Comment: based on what do you consider a value (from the array) is close to the input value ?

Comment: And binary search only works on a sorted dataset, if it is sometimes ascending and sometimes descending, that isn't sorted.

Comment: @Paulpro if you have noticed, the whole row is shifted by 1 - if value is smaller than first value, it return 0 insted of -1 - just for "my" needed

Answer (score 0):

If the data is always ascending or descending, you could do a binary ascending or a binary descending search, then you can check which of the found results is the closest one:

```
function closestIndex(value, arr, compare, from = 0, to = arr.length) {

  if (from >= to) return to;
  const mid = Math.floor((from + to) / 2);
  if (compare(arr[mid], value)) {
    return closestIndex(value, arr, compare, from, mid);
  }
  return closestIndex(value, arr, compare, mid + 1, to);
}

function searchClosest(value, arr) {
  const minIndex = closestIndex(value, arr, (a, b) => a <= b);
  const maxIndex = closestIndex(value, arr, (a, b) => a >= b);
 return Math.abs(arr[minIndex] - value) > Math.abs(arr[maxIndex] - value) ? maxIndex : minIndex;
}
```

Note that this is still O(log n).

Comment: I haven't yet thought about edgecases, e.g. if a value is larger than the biggest valze in the array or smaller than the smallest. In that case, searching in both directions won't yield a result, and therefore the comparison will return `minIndex`, no matter if thats right or wrong. I'm not going to fix this, thats up to you, dear reader :)

Comment: Why I don't want sort data is that data are already sorted - can be asc (like IDs 0,1,4,15,18,...) or desc (like times in timestamp format > new time has higher value than older) - also there are differences between standard closest index function (like your, which I dont want) - if a value is smaller than the smallest, in this case return -1 (like non-existent index) - try this edited demo https://jsfiddle.net/aubns9Lp/ (index is down by 1 to for understanding)